# Broken String object - Arduino

Tags: c, string, arduino

I'm using an Arduino platform with the Asynclabs library (an open-source wifi library for old yellowjacket and redback wifi boards).

Something is breaking the Arduino String object (note the capital S).

I'm using just a simple test:

```
Serial.println("Test Strings:\n");
String junk = "Do Strings print or what?";
Serial.println(junk);
while (1) { delay(2000); Serial.print("+");}
```

This prints as you'd expect at the start of my setup() block. When I move it to after the wifi.init() call, it still works. But when I move it after a call to a short network interaction, it is ignored as if it isn't there. No output is generated other than the first print w/o the String object.

Everything compiles okay - I'd have hoped the compiler would've told me if I had library collisions. 
I grep'd thru the library files for other uses of the word 'String' and 'string' but have seen nothing much there.  I renamed a file called strings.c to canned_strings.c.  Still no improvement.

I'm at a bit of a loss. Any sugg of other things to look for?
[One note - I see several of the library files are including `<string.h>` - is this a deprecated Arduino lib file that should be switched to something else? Investigating... ]

-Ross

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code in? It's at least missing a `"` in the first line.

Comment: Minor typo while editing for television.

Comment: Is only thing that doesn't print after the function call the second print statement?

Comment: Also println and \n seem to be redundant in the first print

Comment: Yes only the String 'junk' doesn't print.  Obviously disregard the \n if you like, I added an extra blank line there for drama at some point - a rather irrelevant detail.

Comment: Currently working on the possibility of SRAM overload, after reading that String() objects are particular memory hogs.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it was clear that the String object is way too RAM intensive for the compact resources of the Arduino.

I got around the problem by eliminating all use of the String type from the code, and using char arrays with lots of pointers. This was much more RAM friendly.

[Also - in the Asynclabs Wifi library, it was helpful to reduce the size of the packet, to further free up some RAM.  Highly recommended strategy to make any progress.]